# Não consigo exibir o valor do SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-select

Estou tentando iniciar uma conexão com o banco de dados MySQL e funciona, porém quando eu solicito que o PHP exiba o que tem lá não aparece nada. É como se a conexão com o *BD* tivesse falhado.

```
<?php
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$server = "";
$usuario = "";
$banco   = "";
$senha = "";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$conexao = mysql_connect($server, $usuario, $senha);
$conexao = mysql_select_db("$banco",$conexao);
if(!$conexao) {echo mysql_error(); exit;}

$conexao = mysql_query("select * from settingsMDP");
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($conexao));
?><?php echo $exibe["name"]; ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Nome do MDP: </td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $exibe["name"]; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Versão: </td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $exibe["version"]; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Abertura do painel:</td>
<td><input name="start_acp" type="text" id="startacp" value="<?php echo $exibe["startacp"]; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Salvar">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Tenham em mente que as informações da conexão estão corretas, se não ia surgir um erro, certo? Por que não consigo ver o valor dentro dos respectivos campos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mudei uma coisa que está obviamente errada. Não sei se vai produzir o resultado que você espera mas pelo menos te mostra onde está o erro.

Você encerrou o `while` com um `;`. Ele não vai ficar repetindo desta forma. Este comando espera um bloco de de outros comandos que será repetido até que a condição seja falsa. Você tem que definir este bloco com chaves. Na verdade quando é uma linha não precisa mas todo bom programador não se importa com isto e sempre usa chaves para facilitar capturar erros e evitar futuros problemas em manutenção.

Você provavelmente achou que a linha abaixo do `while` com um `echo` estava sendo executada repetidas vezes mas não está.

É possível que tenha mais erros mas não consegui localizar já que não posso testar este código.

Eu espero que o `select` no banco de dados esteja retornando alguma coisa e tenha um campo chamado `name`, caso contrário temos outro problema mas desta vez no banco de dados. Na verdade pela forma como está o código HTML espero que só retorne uma linha. Se retornar várias, a página ficará um caos.

Posso considerar que só terá uma linha no banco de dados ou pelo menos que a primeira é que será relevante neste caso? Assim acho que faz mais sentido no que parece ser o que você deseja fazer. Vou mudar o código considerando assim e então não precisa do `while` mais. O `while` só seria necessário se você quisesse ler várias linhas que eu acho que não é o caso.

```
<?php
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
$server = "";
$usuario = "";
$banco   = "";
$senha = "";
// conecta ao banco de dados
$conexao = mysql_connect($server, $usuario, $senha);
$conexao = mysql_select_db("$banco",$conexao);
if(!$conexao) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$conexao = mysql_query("select * from settingsMDP");

//********************************************mudei aqui*****************************
$exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($conexao);
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Nome do MDP: </td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $exibe["name"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Versão: </td>
            <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $exibe["version"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100">Abertura do painel:</td>
            <td><input name="start_acp" type="text" id="startacp" value="<?php echo $exibe["startacp"]; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100"> </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100"> </td>
            <td><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Salvar"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/RetrieveData.php).

Depois pode criar validações para os dados e pode atualizar os novos dados no banco de dados com `update`.

Comment: Sim amigo, bom dia! Foi seu código a solução do problema. No mais eu agradeço imensamente a sua ajuda. :) Ele teria que retornar uma só linha mesmo. Não há mais do que isso. Aiás, queria saber se, usar o recurso UPDATE consigo fazer as devidas validações neste formulário mesmo. É possível?

Comment: Respondendo seu último comentário na resposta removida: Se é o mesmo problema é melhor editar sua pergunta para colocar mais informações. Se é outro problema (mesmo que seja no mesmo código), é melhor colocar postar outra pergunta, senão descaracteriza esta. Aqui não é um fórum, é um *site* de perguntas e respostas. Por isso é importante manter organizado. Ou seja, se você conseguiu evoluir um pouco e agora precisa resolver outro detalhe deste código, é outra pergunta.

Comment: Okay. Então, obrigado.